# DropDownList events don't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I’m having trouble with my DropDownList. The events don’t fire! I've tested it on a separate project, with a DropDownList and a literal. Every time the selected value would change, I would add a little star “*” to the literal. No problems what so ever. But every time I try it on my webpage in the project, it fails.

[Here](http://i46.tinypic.com/2cgbrs4.jpg) is an image.

```
protected void ddlConsole_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ltlTesting.Text += "*";
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've tried some things but still with no succes. I hope someone can tell me what i'm doing wrong. I'm wiring the events in the code behind now, but i've added a linkbutton next to the dropdownlist to see if it works.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        ddlConsole.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlConsole_SelectedIndexChanged);
        lnkGet.Click += new EventHandler(ddlConsole_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }
```

[image]

Here is an image to see what's going on. The stripe in the literal at the beginning is added in pageload with the same code the star is added. Just to be sure it doesn't load twice. The "GET" linkbutton works fine. The dropdownlist doesn't...

Comment: I didn't ment it that way. I'm just a little frustrated because i can't make it work, and i have the feeling it's something really small that i'm looking over. You have quite the reputation yourself, any sugestions?

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out I think is your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you Set

```
AutoPostBack="true"
```

in control properties??

**EDIT:**

Remove

> ```
> OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlConsole_SelectedIndexChanged"
> ```

from the markup in the ASPX page and try again only with AutoPostback true and the
event defined in codebehind. The aspx page should look like this:

```
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlConsole" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. I've tried this.

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            ddlConsole.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlConsole_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }

No succes :(

Answer (score 0):

Is the `AutoPostBack` of the dropdownlist `true` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check AutopostBack property of Dropdownlist  set it to true :

Answer (score 0):

If picture is right and the `AutoPostBack="True"`, is there any code that sets the value of `ltlTesting` when page loads?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `AutoPostback="True"` and `OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlConsole_SelectedIndexChanged"` to the ddlConsole attributes. You can delete the `OnInit` method, since you bound the SeletedIndexChanged event at design time.